Can Time Machine backup to a folder on a Samba Share?
I have a Samba shared folder set up via an OpenWrt router.  One sub-folder is currently used to perform an encrypted backup of a Linux machine with Déjà Dup.  I created another sub-folder which I intend to use for backing up a Mac laptop. These docs suggest that I'll need to format the disk in order to make a backup with time machine.  Does Time Machine really only backup if it can format the disk all for itself?  Or can it backup to one folder, or, failing that, its own partition?

Those comments are for directly-connected backup volumes.

FWIW, I'm going through something similar. But for starters, does the Samba folder have a setting within the OpenWRT router to enable Time Machine?

Time machine will not work with a samba share, afaik. One issue is how time machine works, it cannot work on Samba. It creates hard-links, iirc, which is why it will not work, imho.

You're describing how it works on a directly-connected volume.  On a network share, it creates a disk image and writes to that.
